# PDE ( Cauchy Problem) prove on the existence and uniqueness of solution.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

If the carrier \Gamma (smooth curve) of the Cauchy data is not tangent to the characteristic curves $$\frac{dx}{P(x,y,z)}=\frac{dy}{Q(x,y,z)}=\frac{dz}{R(x,y,z)}$$ at each of its points, then a local solution of the Cauchy problem $$P_p+Q_q=R,\forall(x,y,z)\in U$$
$$Z= Z_0(s), \frac{dz_0}{ds}= P_0(s)\frac{dx_0}{ds}+Q_0(s)\frac{dy_0}{ds},(x,y,z)\in \Gamma $$ exist and is unique.